# Example Bayesian resolution of the Two Envelopes Problem

Tags: bayesian, expected-value

What is a concrete example of a Bayesian resolution to the [Two Envelopes Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_envelopes_problem)?

Answer (score 1):

## Setup

Suppose the experimenter chooses a small and a large quantity.  The smaller quantity is chosen from the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) whose [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is given by
$$f(x) = e^{-x}$$
and the larger quantity is set to be double the small amount.

[image]

The two quantities are then placed into two envelopes at random, meaning the first envelope has the larger quantity with a 50% probability.  Let the amount in the first envelope be denoted by $A$ and the amount in the second envelope be denoted by $B$.

Note that $A$ and $B$ are dependent random variables.

## Using Bayes rule

We can use Bayes rules to calculate the probability of $B$ being the large quantity given that we observe $A$ to take the value $a$.  Keeping in mind that 
$$P(B\text{ is larger})=P(B\text{ is smaller})=\frac{1}{2}\;\;,$$ 
we have

\begin{align}
P(B\text{ is larger}| A=a) &=\frac
{P(A=a| B\text{ is larger})\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}
{P(A=a| B\text{ is larger})\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+P(A=a| B\text{ is smaller})\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}  
\end{align}

If $B$ is the larger amount, then that means $A$ is the smaller amount and was chosen from the above exponential distribution, thus
$$P(A=a| B\text{ is larger})= e^{-a}\;\;.  $$

If $B$ is the smaller amount, then $A$ is just double the outcome of the above exponential distribution, and the PDF would be
$$P(A=a| B\text{ is smaller})= \frac{1}{2}e^\frac{-a}{2}\;\;.  $$

We can thus simplify Bayes rule to be
$$ P(B\text{ is larger}| A=a) = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}e^\frac{a}{2}} \tag{0}$$
and we can also get that
\begin{align}
P(B\text{ is smaller}| A=a) =&\; 1 - P(B\text{ is larger}| A=a)
\\
=&\; \frac{1}{1+2e^\frac{-a}{2}}
\end{align}

## Expected Increase of a Switch

We want to calculate the expected increase of switching envelopes from A to B.

First start by assuming that we've observed $A$ to be $a$, then the expected increase of switching is
\begin{align}
E[(B-A) | A=a] =&\; (a)P(B\text{ is larger}| A=a) + \left(\frac{-a}{2}\right)P(B\text{ is smaller}| A=a)
\\
               =&\; (a)\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}e^\frac{a}{2}} + \left(\frac{-a}{2}\right) \frac{1}{1+2e^\frac{-a}{2}} \tag{1}
\end{align}

Let's take this a step further and say we don't look at the amount in the first envelope.  We'd like to know the the expected increase not conditioned on anything, i.e. $E[(B-A)]$.  To get this, we just need to integrate over $a$,
$$E[(B-A)] = \int_0^\infty E[(B-A) | A=a] \;\;P(A=a) \;da    \tag{2} $$

To calculate $P(A=a)$, we just use the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability),
\begin{align}
P(A=a) =&\; P(A=a|A\text{ is smaller})P(A\text{ is smaller}) \\
         &\;+ P(A=a|A\text{ is larger})P(A\text{ is larger})  \\
       =&\; \left(e^{-a}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2}e^\frac{-a}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \tag{3}
\end{align}

Finally, if you plug Eqns (1) and (3) into Eqn (2) and use a computer to analytically integrate, you will get the intuitively pleasing result of
$$\boxed{E[(B-A)]=0}$$

## Intuition

Let's suppose you know about the experimenter's method for setting up the experiment, including the fact that he's using the exponential distribution.

You pick up the envelope with $A$.  Without looking inside, it is indeed true from a Bayesian perspective, that the other envelope has a 50% chance of having double and a 50% chance of having half.  So it seems you should switch, which is absurd!

You can gain some insight, by imaging actually observing $A$.  Looking at the exponential distribution below, we see that most of the time, our envelope will contain a small number.  Suppose you observed \$0.42 in your envelope.  Plugging $a=0.42$ into equation (0), you'll see that the probability that the other envelope has more is 61.8%.

So switching still sounds good, but on some extremely rare occasions, you're going to open the envelope and see a large amount, say $10.  From equation (0), the probability of the other envelope having more is 1.3% so you're not going to want to switch.  Also, note that these events, while very rare, count for more.

Going back to the case of not being allowed to look in the envelope, these two effects balance each other out meaning switching will give you no increased benefit.  Might as well just open your envelope and be happy.  If you are allowed to open the envelope though, I highly recommend it before deciding to switch or not.

## More Intuition

I chose the exponential distribution as my setup, but you'd come to similar conclusions with other distributions used for the setup, but with slightly different intuitions.  For example, you could have used the uniform distribution.  This is what might be used in practice, since real people have strict bounds on their personal wealth.

If you ever find Bill Gates offering you two envelopes and you're not allowed to look inside, there's no point in switching.  If however, you are allowed to look inside and you find envelope A to have \$40 billion, I'd recommend not switching.  (hint: given Bill Gates' total net worth of $78 billion, what's the probability of the other envelope having more?)

Comment: @Xi'an, maybe nothing, but why does an answer need to have something new?

Comment: @Xi'an, I haven't discovered anything new (otherwise I probably would have submitted a journal article instead).  As for the Q&A, Stack Exchange explicitly encourages asking and answering your own question (see [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)).  If you're curious about my personal motivation, this answer actually started as a question where I was asking why my math wasn't working out, but just before posting, I found my error.  I decided to share for anyone else going down this same route in the future who struggles like I did.

Comment: Although your effort at posting this answer is appreciated, it doesn't appear to be a "Bayesian resolution" in the sense that any Bayesian would understand: it merely employs Bayes' Theorem after making an (unsupported) additional assumption that the experimenter chooses a number according to some specific distribution. A truly Bayesian resolution would not make or need such an arbitrary assumption: it would propose a solution absent any knowledge of the experimenter's procedure. It is only at the last paragraph that any Bayesian reasoning seems to be employed--but only in a qualitative way.